# Has anyone used No Lock with Power BI?

Tags: locking, powerbi

I have some Power BI queries which are very slow and causing issues on our server.  It was suggested that I use No Lock.  I've used this in SQL, but I can't find any way to do this in Power BI.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would write SQL SELECT statements to start each Query, using the NOLOCK hint.  Then I would paste those into the Get Data / SQL Server / Advanced / SQL Statement box.

You may be able to avoid this by optimising your Query steps to make them run faster, e.g. moving SQL-translatable steps like Filter, Group By, Remove Columns etc as far up the Steps list as possible.